# Mass email Visualforce email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

I understand that visualforce templates cannot be mass emailed. Is it possible to put a single email method in a loop? I also understand that lists in loops are bad!

I have tried to cut up this [post](http://burnignorance.com/salesforce-tips/sending-mass-email-through-apex-controllers/) to suit the requirement.

APEX:

```
public PageReference sendEmail(){   

ID currentRecordID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ID');
emailTemplate et = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'ABS Trainer - Unit Confirmation - Online' LIMIT 1];

List<Contact> contactNames = [SELECT id, name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: currentRecordID LIMIT 200];
    for (String obj : contactNames){
        contact = [SELECT Id,name,email FROM Contact WHERE name =:obj];
        for(Integer i=0; i < contact.size(); i++){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setTargetObjectId(contact[i].Id);
            email.setTemplateId(et.id);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
        }  
    }
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Email Sent Successfully'));
return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EmailTemplate et = [ SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'ABS Trainer - Unit Confirmation - Online' LIMIT 1 ];
List<Contact> contacts = [ SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: currentRecordId LIMIT 200 ];
Set<String> addresses = new Set<String>();

for( Contact c : contacts ){
    if( !addresses.Contains( c.Email ) ){ addresses.Add( c.Email ); }
}

string[] toAddresses = new string[ addresses.size() ];

Integer i = 0;
for( String address : addresses ){
    toAddresses[ i ] = address;
    i++;
}

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
email.setTemplateId( et.Id );
Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ email } );
```

try this!

Add your to addresses to an array and send the template to this array of Contact Email Addresses

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. There seems to be an issue with the syntax (line 11) - Compile Error: Missing ';' at 'email'.

Comment: Oops, i typed. - instead of = I'll edit.

Comment: Response updated, easy slip of the finger, should have been easy to figure out on your end looking at that line. Should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. There is a new error - Compile Error: Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: String but was: Set<String> at line 8

Comment: so add all of the emails to the array as strings in a for loop

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. Please can you update your answer so that others will benefit

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh updated! my earlier comment was while away - would have done so previously.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. A new error when pressing the button that calls this function - System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template: []